# Crystal Report and C# - Changing the Text Object Color depends on Value

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I'm totally new in C# and crystal report, it is possible to change the font color
of text object in Crystal Report depends on value that have been shown?.
example, if the value was "6PM-6AM" the text object color should be RED else it will black.
I know i need to go in Formula Workshop, I write this code but still nothings happen.
how can I do it? thank you.

```
If {DataTable11.1_Date}="2PM-10PM"
  Then crRed 
Else crBlue
```

Comment: This is VB.NET code?

Comment: what do you mean? I write the code in Crystal Report.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by writing the same formula in `Formula Workshop` of the font.. Follow the below process:

1. Rightclick on `text object ----> Format Filed ---> Font Tab ---> click x-2 button of the color.`

Write your formula in that window

Edit-----------------

Try this: Lenghty way but works

```
If {DataTable11.1_Date} IN ["2PM", "3PM", "4PM", "5PM","6PM", "7PM", "8PM","9PM",10PM"]
  Then crRed 
Else crBlue
```

Comment: I do what you've said ,i write the code and got no error but still nothing happen, even the value is "2PM-10PM" i still got the color blue in the text object

Comment: what type of data is store in `{DataTable11.1_Date}` I mean what is the format?

Comment: hmm what format? it's supposedly STRING, am i missing something?

Comment: thanks for answering but still not working, what was your code that you give do?? by the way the data was from the database then transfer from the system, and when the user trigger the button print preview the data from the system will pass to the textobject, that how it works. so it was still a string right?

Comment: difficult to answer... what is the datatype in database?

Comment: It was TEXT in database, i'm using SQL server 2008. but before I pass the data in crystal report i've converted it into String

Comment: If it is string then solution in my edit should work....check the data retrived by the crystal report...if you get correct data solution should work

Comment: I find the answer :) i use the Highlighting expert. thanks for the time.